# Get entrypoint name in webpack loader

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-loader

I have a bunch of webpack entrypoints configured as described [here](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#multi-page-application):

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    pageOne: './src/pageOne.js’,
    pageTwo: './src/pageTwo.js’,
    pageThree: './src/pageThree.js’
  }
}
```

The entries themselves import various modules.
E.g. **pageOne.js** imports **module1.js**

I am also using the [skeleton loader](https://github.com/anseki/skeleton-loader) to act on the raw javascript content (of **pageOne.js, pageTwo.js**, …)

This loaders callback function´s “this” refers to the [“loader context”](https://webpack.js.org/api/loaders/#the-loader-context)

My Question:
So now I have the files content (e.g. of **module1.js**) and its corresponding loader context (via this) in the callback. But I need to know the (original/parent) entry name of **module1.js**. So for **module1.js** it should tell me that it is part of the original **pageOne** entry name. Is that possible?

Comment: Did you solve this?